# Filter elements in deeply nested array

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like below:

```
[
  {
    "array1": [
      {
        "array2": [
          {
            "array3": [ 1, 2 ]
          },
          {
            "array3": [ 2, 3 ]
          },
          {
            "array3": [ 3, 4 ]
          },
          {
            "array3": [ 4, 5 ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I want to filter only `array2` elements that contain 1 or 5 within `array3`.
An input like this:

```
[
  {
    "array1": [
      {
        "array2": [
          {
            "array3": [ 1, 2 ]
          },
          {
            "array3": [ 4, 5 ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried the `$filter` operator with this aggregation but it is not working as expected.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "array1.array2": {
        $filter: {
          "input": "$array1.array2",
          "cond": {
            "$in": [
              "$$this.array3",
              [ 1, 5 ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XqEejtoCc_3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think that you should iterate each element in the `array1` array and filter the element in the `array2` array which contains 1, 5 by `$setIntersection` and `$ne` (not equal to empty array) operators.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "array1": {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $map: {
              input: "$array1",
              as: "array1",
              in: {
                array2: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$$array1.array2",
                    cond: {
                      $ne: [
                        {
                          $setIntersection: [
                            "$$this.array3",
                            [
                              1,
                              5
                            ]
                          ]
                        },
                        []
                      ]
                    },
                    
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              "$$this.array2",
              []
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CavD446ReuR)

Comment: why using `$setIntersection` over `$in` ? isn't the same thing ?

Comment: if I add another item with no `array2` element matching the criteria then I got empty array https://mongoplayground.net/p/40VQEM3sMZ2

Comment: You could add `$filter` operator to filter `array2` is not empty array. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CavD446ReuR)

Comment: Meanwhile why `$setIntersection` over `$in`, both are different, the purpose of `$setIntersection` aims to find the element exist in both arrays. If you use `$in`, yo are comparing the whole array with array, but not each element against the array.